# C# Thread Tasks Not running Sequentially

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an application which plays a recording stream, it has a COM Interface to provide functionality to start replay stream along with other control variables. I want to accomplish the following task (test case) using an button click event (Visual Studio Desktop Form Application):

1. Play recording from 0 second (0 min) for 10 seconds
2. Then play recording from 60 second (1 min) for 15 seconds
3. Finally play recording from 120 second (2 min) for 20 seconds. (stream length in approx 3 min)

I am creating thread for each of the above task from 1-3 and then I am using join method to wait for each task to be completed and then start the next thread.

**My code:**

```
private void btnReplayForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

Thread replayAtThread = new Thread(() => mpd.startReplayAt3(0, 10));
replayAtThread.Start();
replayAtThread.Join();

Thread replayAtThread1 = new Thread(() => mpd.startReplayAt3(60, 15));
replayAtThread1.Start();
replayAtThread1.Join();

Thread replayAtThread2 = new Thread(() => mpd.startReplayAt3(120, 20));
replayAtThread2.Start();
replayAtThread2.Join();

replayAtThread.Abort();
replayAtThread1.Abort();
replayAtThread2.Abort();
}
```

mpd is just an instance of an class that uses COM Interface, in a nutshell this is what startReplayAt3 method looks like

```
public bool startReplayAt3(double start, double duration)
{
//Set start and duration
//Start replay at start and duration values     
bool isReplay = //get replay value, true if replay running, false if stopped

while (isReplay)          
      isReplay = //get replay value, true if replay running, false if stopped

return isReplay;
}
```

However, on the actual interface I am not seeing the desired results, it performs task 1, then does something with task 2 but skip the replay part entirely, then performs task 3. Next time when I click the button, it skips task 1, goes straight to task 2 and ends without performing task 3. So as you can see it is very unpredictable and strange behavior.

Why could be the cause, I am making sure that my thread are in sync but it doesn't seem to reflect in the UI of the application I am running.

Comment: Your usage of threads appears to be completely wrong. It's unclear how the StartReplay method is working. And we can't answer as we don't know what `mpd` is, so we can't tell you how to control its execution.

Comment: I clearly stated about what mpd is and how StartReplay work. Would you like to elaborate a little more on why my usage of thread is completely wrong?

Comment: No, you didn't clearly state what mpd is.  You don't show the variable's type and you haven't said "mpd is..." anywhere in your question. You hint at "a COM Interface", is that it? We don't know how "a COM Interface" works, whether calls to it block or not, etc.  As to the threading, it's odd that you would spawn a thread just to call what may be (again, not enough info in your question) a synchronous method only to block the current thread.  *Does* startReplayAt3 block, or does it return immediately?  Do you see why your question is a little unclear?

Comment: The threading code just smells of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). It might be because the snippets provided have been cut down for your question, or it might be because you're cargo-culting.

Comment: My first question is "Why are you using threads here?"

Comment: because without threads, each line of code with startReplayAt3 executes quickly in my code but its actual interaction of replaying stream at particular intervals with the mpd application is more or less simultaneous, so only the last replay interval is played while the rest is skipped, with threads I get a better result but still not the desired one. I realize now that  I should use some sort of locking mechanism such as semaphore or mutex to make sure other threads can't access the resource while one is using it. I think this may be the problem, correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure about the issue you're seeing with the threads :\.  The implementation seems a little off, the .Abort() calls seem redundant since the thread will be completed by the time you're calling the .Abort().

Why not use asynchronous functionality?

```
await Task.Run(() => mpd.startReplayAt3(0, 10));

await Task.Run(() => mpd.startReplayAt3(60, 15));

await Task.Run(() => mpd.startReplayAt3(120, 20));
```

or:

```
var replayTasks = new List<Task>();

replayTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => mpd.startReplayAt3(0, 10)));

replayTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => mpd.startReplayAt3(60, 15)));

replayTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => mpd.startReplayAt3(120, 20)));

Task.WaitAll(replayTasks.ToArray());
```

or:

```
var replayTasks = new Task[] {
    Task.Run(() => mpd.startReplayAt3(0, 10)),
    Task.Run(() => mpd.startReplayAt3(60, 15)),
    Task.Run(() => mpd.startReplayAt3(120, 20))
};

Task.WaitAll(replayTasks);
```

Like yourself I used to create many threads for executing tasks simultaneously, but I have fallen in love with async/await.

Make sure to change your _Click method to an asynchronous method using the async keyword.

Comment: which method should be async, the click event method or that mpd.startReplayAt3 ?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  Edited. (The _Click method should be async and include the await keyword.)

Comment: I tried the above, but the problem remains, how your answer was very information.

Comment: Worth noting:  My first example will have all 3 run in series, one after the other.  My other 2 examples all 3 threads will be running in parallel.

Comment: well I have single process of an application open, so desired functionality is running  one after the other.

Answer (score 2):

From your description of the program's behavior, it seems to me that `startReplayAt3` in fact only *starts* the replay.

What you want to do is start the replay, *then wait until it finishes*, and *then* start the next replay.

If the COM object gives you an event that is raised when the replay completes, then you're good; you should [wrap that event into a task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#EAP), and use `await` to consume it, something like this:

```
public static Task ReplayAsync(this MPD mpd, int start, int duration)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
  ReplayFinishedHandler handler = null;
  handler = (s, e) => { tcs.TrySetCompleted(); mpd.ReplayFinished -= handler; };
  mpd.ReplayFinished += handler;
  mpd.startReplayAt3(start, duration);
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

used as such:

```
private async void btnReplayForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await mpd.ReplayAsync(0, 10);
  await mpd.ReplayAsync(60, 15);
  await mpd.ReplayAsync(120, 20);
}
```

But some COM objects don't let you know when they're done (notably, a lot of media players are really bad at this). In that case, you'll either have to poll some kind of `IsPlaying` flag on the COM object, or just use a timeout like this:

```
public static Task ReplayAsync(this MPD mpd, int start, int duration)
{
  mpd.startReplayAt3(start, duration);
  return Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration));
}
```